# Python distributed computing over LAN

Tags: python, parallel-processing, firewall, distributed-computing

Most of my work involves "embarrassingly parallel" computations, i.e. relatively CPU heavy tasks looped over a range of parameters without any need for communication between the individual computations.

I would like to be able to share computations between my workplace PC and my home PC (and potentially other workplace PCs).

My question is about how to achieve this in the most easy manner. All PCs are behind firewalls, but the PCs at the workplace share a common domain (Windows), if it makes a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need a solid distributed computing/communication backend (unless you're crazy enough to write one yourself) like [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org/), [dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/) and such. Your question is too broad otherwise.

Comment: [ipyparallel](https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel) is probably the easiest and automatically able to use zeromq and co.